# Get all files from dir and all subdirs EXCEPT one subdir

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-console

I currently use this line in a Windows batch file:

```
@ REM List all *.f in current dir and all its subdirs
dir *.f /B /S > temp1.txt
```

Unfortunately, one of the subdirs (let's name it `pest`) has a very large subtree, which makes the process quite slow. Since the `pest` subdir is actually unimportant for this specific task (it is not supposed to contain any relevant file), I would like to exclude it from the search.

So, instead of searching in current and all subdirs, I would like to search in current dir and all subdirs except `pest`.

Can you propose a simple way to do that?

Comment: Pipe the results of the `DIR` command to the `FIND` command and use the /V option with the `FIND` Command.

Comment: @Squashman, this does not prevent `dir /S` from enumerating the directory, which is the intention of the question, as far as I got it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pest` is an immediate subdirectory of the root (that is the current directory, `.`), you could do the following:

```dos
rem // Enumerate immediate child files in the root, output them:
> "temp1.txt" (for %%F in (".\*.f") do @echo %%~fF)
rem // Enumerate immediate subdirectories of the root:
>>"temp1.txt" (
    for /D %%D in (".\*.*") do @(
        rem // Skip the rest if current subdirectory is the one to exclude:
        if /I not "%%~nxD"=="pest" (
            rem // Output all files found in the current subdirectory recursively:
            pushd "%%~D"
            for /R %%E in ("*.f") do @echo %%~E
            popd
        )
    )
)
```

This returns files only but no directories; if you want such to be included too, try the following code:

```dos
rem // Output the path to the root directory itself:
> "temp1.txt" (for /D %%D in (".") do @echo %%~fD)
rem // Enumerate immediate child files in the root, output them:
>>"temp1.txt" (for %%F in (".\*.f") do @echo %%~fF)
rem // Enumerate immediate subdirectories of the root:
>>"temp1.txt" (
    for /D %%D in (".\*.*") do @(
        rem // Skip the rest if current subdirectory is the one to exclude:
        if /I not "%%~nxD"=="pest" (
            rem // Output the current subdirectory:
            echo %%~fD
            rem // Output all files found in the current subdirectory recursively:
            for /F "eol=| delims=" %%E in ('dir /B /S "%%~D\*.f"') do @echo %%E
        )
    )
)
```

---

If the `pest` subdirectory can be anywhere in the tree, you might use this approach:

```dos
@echo off
rem /* Call subroutine with the root directory (the current one), the file pattern
rem    and the name of the directory to exclude as arguments: */
> "temp1.txt" call :SUB "." "*.f" "pest"
exit /B

:SUB  val_dir_path  val_file_pattern  val_dir_exclude
rem // Output directory (optionally):
echo %~f1
rem // Enumerate immediate child files and output them:
for %%F in ("%~1\%~2") do echo %%~fF
rem // Enumerate immediate subdirectories:
for /D %%D in ("%~1\*.*") do (
    rem // Skip the rest if current subdirectory is the one to exclude:
    if /I not "%%~nxD"=="%~3" (
        rem /* Recursively call subroutine with the current subdirectory, the file pattern
        rem    and the name of the directory to exclude as arguments: */
        call :SUB "%%~D" "%~2" "%~3"
    )
)
```

To avoid subdirectories to be output also, simply remove the command line `echo %~f1`.

Since this approach features recursive subroutine calls, the performance is noticeably worse than using a simple `dir /S` command in case there is no `pest` subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks. Your first version does exactly what I need it to.

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider to **accept** the answer by clicking the green checkmark. Read the following help topics to learn what this means and why this is important: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the directory exclusion facility in RoboCopy:

```cmd
@Echo Off

(Set SrcDir=C:\Users\Parker\Documents)
(Set SrcMsk=*.f)
(Set ToExcl=pest)
(Set OutPut=temp1.txt)

>"%OutPut%" (For /F "Tokens=*" %%A In ('RoboCopy "%SrcDir%" NULL %SrcMsk%^
 /L /S /FP /NDL /NS /NC /NJH /NJS /XD "%ToExcl%"') Do Echo=%%A)
```

Make your relevant changes in the four parenthesesed lines as necessary.

Comment: For some reason this returns not just *.f files but simply all of them ?

Comment: Apologies, there is a typo in my answer, _(it said %ScrMsk% instead of  %SrcMsk%)_, now fixed.